# How to retrieve version of my npm application without importing other package.json info?

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

I have an SPA application (in *React*) built with *Webpack* (as part of *create-react-app*) where I display a version number retrieved from the `package.json` likes this:

```
import npmInfo from 'package.json'
...
<div className="version">{npmInfo.version}</div>
```

However this results in also other `package.json` being part of built javascript file and exposed to the public.

Is there an approach to retrieve just the `version` from `package.json` other than reading it in parent the process and setting it to environment variable (and reading it via `process.env.VERSION`) ?

Comment: Will that actually end up in the built result? I'd imagine unused info will be tree-shaken or otherwise optimised out.

Comment: Try `import { version } from 'package.json', does that work?

Comment: @casraf No, it still adds the whole `package.json`

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is there as a JSON

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, as you are a bit against using (or rather setting?) environment variables, but if your application is ran or compiled by a npm script, you could use `process.env.npm_package_version`.

Note: this will only be available if you use npm scripts.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction but this method unfortunately does not work with *create-react-app*. But I was inspired by it and ended up with `cross-env REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version react-scripts start` script.

Comment: Great! It'd be cool if you could write an answer about it, so others will be able to notice the solution.

Comment: I intend to but I am not that happy with the aforementioned solution. When I have more time I will try to find out more about this and post the best solution I could come with.